# EasyAI SOS Game - Scoring and AI Play Issues

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I'm working on an SOS game implementation using EasyAI, and I've encountered a couple of issues with the scoring and AI player.

```
from easyAI import TwoPlayerGame, Human_Player, AI_Player, Negamax

class SOSgame(TwoPlayerGame):
  def __init__(self, players):
    self.board = [[''] * 6 for _ in range(6) ]  # Create a 6x6 board
    self.players = players
    self.nplayer = 1
    self.human_player_score = 0
    self.ai_player_score = 0
    self.stored_scores = {}  # Dictionary to store scores for SOS sequences
    super().__init__()

  def possible_moves(self):
    moves = []
    for row in range(6):
        for col in range(6):
            if self.board[row][col] == '':
                moves.append((row, col, 'S'))
                moves.append((row, col, 'O'))
    return moves

def make_move(self, move):
    row, col, move_type = move
    self.board[row][col] = move_type

  def win(self):
    if self.human_player_score > self.ai_player_score:
        return 1
    elif self.human_player_score < self.ai_player_score:
        return -1
    else:
        return 0

  def is_draw(self):
    return all(cell != '' for row in self.board for cell in row)

  def is_over(self):
    return self.win() != 0

  def scoring(self):
    sos_count = 0
    for i in range(6):
        for j in range(6):
            if (j + 2 < 6) and (self.board[i][j] == 'S' and self.board[i][j + 1] == 'O' and self.board[i][j + 2] == 'S'):
                sos_count += 1
                if self.nplayer == 1:
                    self.stored_scores[(i, j, 'S')] = self.stored_scores.get((i, j, 'S'), 0) + 1
                else:
                    self.stored_scores[(i, j, 'O')] = self.stored_scores.get((i, j, 'O'), 0) + 1

            if (i + 2 < 6) and (self.board[i][j] == 'S' and self.board[i + 1][j] == 'O' and self.board[i + 2][j] == 'S'):
                sos_count += 1
                if self.nplayer == 1:
                    self.stored_scores[(i, j, 'S')] = self.stored_scores.get((i, j, 'S'), 0) + 1
                else:
                    self.stored_scores[(i, j, 'O')] = self.stored_scores.get((i, j, 'O'), 0) + 1

            if (i + 2 < 6 and j + 2 < 6) and (self.board[i][j] == 'S' and self.board[i + 1][j + 1] == 'O' and self.board[i + 2][j + 2] == 'S'):
                sos_count += 1
                if self.nplayer == 1:
                    self.stored_scores[(i, j, 'S')] = self.stored_scores.get((i, j, 'S'), 0) + 1
                else:
                    self.stored_scores[(i, j, 'O')] = self.stored_scores.get((i, j, 'O'), 0) + 1

            if (i - 2 >= 0 and j + 2 < 6) and (self.board[i][j] == 'S' and self.board[i - 1][j + 1] == 'O' and self.board[i - 2][j + 2] == 'S'):
                sos_count += 1
                if self.nplayer == 1:
                    self.stored_scores[(i, j, 'S')] = self.stored_scores.get((i, j, 'S'), 0) + 1
                else:
                    self.stored_scores[(i, j, 'O')] = self.stored_scores.get((i, j, 'O'), 0) + 1

    return sos_count

  def show(self):
    for row in self.board:
        print(" ".join(cell if cell else '_' for cell in row))
    print("=====")
    print(f"Player 1 (Human) Score: {self.human_player_score}")
    print(f"Player 2 (AI) Score: {self.ai_player_score}")

    if self.is_over():
        if self.win() > 0:
            print("Player 1 (Human) wins!")
        elif self.win() < 0:
            print("Player 2 (AI) wins!")
        else:
            print("The game is a draw!")

  def switch_player(self):
    self.nplayer = 3 - self.nplayer

  def ai_play(self):
    move = self.get_move()
    self.make_move(move)

  def play(self):
    self.show()

    while not self.is_over():
        self.current_player = self.nplayer
        if self.nplayer == 1:
            while True:
                try:
                    move_type = input(f"Player 1, what do you play? Enter 'S' or 'O': ").strip().upper()
                    if move_type in ['S', 'O']:
                        move_input = input("Enter row and column (e.g., '0 1'): ").split()
                        if len(move_input) == 2:
                            row, col = map(int, move_input)
                            move = (row, col, move_type)
                            if move in self.possible_moves():
                                break
                            else:
                                print("Invalid move. Please try again.")
                        else:
                            print("Invalid input. Please enter your move as 'row column'.")
                    else:
                        print("Invalid input. Please enter 'S' or 'O' to specify your move.")
                except ValueError:
                    print("Invalid input. Please enter your move as 'S' or 'O' followed by 'row column.")
            self.make_move(move)
        else:
            move = self.get_move()
            self.make_move(move)
            print(f"Player 2 (AI) plays {move}")

        self.show()
        if self.nplayer == 1:
            self.human_player_score += self.win()
        else:
            self.ai_player_score += abs(self.win())

        if not self.is_over():
            self.switch_player()

    print("Game Over")
    print(f"Player 1 (Human) Score: {self.human_player_score}")
    print(f"Player 2 (AI) Score: {self.ai_player_score}")
if __name__ == '__main__':
   game = SOSgame([Human_Player(), AI_Player(Negamax(5))])
   game.play()
```

`

**I'm facing two main issues:**

**Scoring Not Working:** The scoring method in the SOSgame class is responsible for calculating the SOS sequences, but it seems to be incorrect or incomplete. The AI player's score doesn't update correctly, and I suspect the scoring function is the culprit.

**AI Play Not Good:** The ai_play method is supposed to make moves for the AI player, but it doesn't seem to be performing well. The AI player's moves are not strategic or competitive enough, even with Negamax depth set to 5.

I'd appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to fix these issues. Specifically, if you have insights on how to improve the scoring function for SOS sequences and enhance the AI player's performance, that would be incredibly helpful. Thank you!